# Error in Python code Machine Learning(Iris Flower) using Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I just started learning the basics of Machine Learning and I stumbled to this error.

In the Iris flower problem in Machine Learning, I am facing an error which I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting it.
Can you please explain why I'm facing such errors.

> CODE

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np
#load data
iris= load_iris()

#position of the start of the flower names or indexes
test_index=[0,50,100]

#Training data
train_target = np.delete(iris.target,test_index)
train_data=np.delete(iris.data,test_index)

test_target=iris.target[test_index]
test_data=iris.data[test_index]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf=clf.fit(train_data , train_target)

print(test_target)
```

> ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MachineLearning2.py", line 29, in <module>
    clf=clf.fit(train_data , train_target)
  File "C:\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 790, in fit
    X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
  File "C:\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 116, in fit
    X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
  File "C:\Anacondas\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 441, in check_array
    "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 3.5         1.39999998  0.2         4.9000001   3.          1.39999998
  0.2         4.69999981  3.20000005  1.29999995  0.2         4.5999999
  3.0999999   1.5         0.2         5.          3.5999999   1.39999998
  0.2         5.4000001   3.9000001   1.70000005  0.40000001  4.5999999
  3.4000001   1.39999998  0.30000001  5.          3.4000001   1.5         0.2
  4.4000001   2.9000001   1.39999998  0.2         4.9000001   3.0999999
  1.5         0.1         5.4000001   3.70000005  1.5         0.2
  4.80000019  3.4000001   1.60000002  0.2         4.80000019  3.          0.1
  4.30000019  3.          1.10000002  0.1         5.80000019  4.
  1.20000005  0.2         5.69999981  4.4000001   1.5         0.40000001
  5.4000001   3.9000001   1.29999995  0.40000001  5.0999999   3.5
  1.39999998  0.30000001  5.69999981  3.79999995  1.70000005  0.30000001
  5.0999999   3.79999995  1.5         0.30000001  5.4000001   3.4000001
  1.70000005  0.2         5.0999999   3.70000005  1.5         0.40000001
  4.5999999   3.5999999   1.          0.2         5.0999999   3.29999995
  1.70000005  0.5         4.80000019  3.4000001   1.89999998  0.2         3.
  1.60000002  0.2         5.          3.4000001   1.60000002  0.40000001
  5.19999981  3.5         1.5         0.2         5.19999981  3.4000001
  1.39999998  0.2         4.69999981  3.20000005  1.60000002  0.2
  4.80000019  3.0999999   1.60000002  0.2         5.4000001   3.4000001
  1.5         0.40000001  5.19999981  4.0999999   1.5         0.1         5.5
  4.19999981  1.39999998  0.2         4.9000001   3.0999999   1.5         0.1
  5.          3.20000005  1.20000005  0.2         5.5         3.5
  1.29999995  0.2         4.9000001   3.0999999   1.5         0.1
  4.4000001   3.          1.29999995  0.2         5.0999999   3.4000001
  1.5         0.2         5.          3.5         1.29999995  0.30000001
  4.5         2.29999995  1.29999995  0.30000001  4.4000001   3.20000005
  1.29999995  0.2         5.          3.5         1.60000002  0.60000002
  5.0999999   3.79999995  1.89999998  0.40000001  4.80000019  3.
  1.39999998  0.30000001  5.0999999   3.79999995  1.60000002  0.2
  4.5999999   3.20000005  1.39999998  0.2         5.30000019  3.70000005
  1.5         0.2         5.          3.29999995  1.39999998  0.2         7.
  3.20000005  4.69999981  1.39999998  6.4000001   3.20000005  4.5         1.5
  6.9000001   3.0999999   4.9000001   1.5         5.5         2.29999995
  4.          1.29999995  6.5         2.79999995  4.5999999   1.5
  5.69999981  2.79999995  4.5         1.29999995  6.30000019  3.29999995
  4.69999981  1.60000002  4.9000001   2.4000001   3.29999995  1.          6.5999999
  2.9000001   4.5999999   1.29999995  5.19999981  2.70000005  3.9000001
  1.39999998  5.          2.          3.5         1.          5.9000001   3.
  4.19999981  1.5         6.          2.20000005  4.          1.          6.0999999
  2.9000001   4.69999981  1.39999998  5.5999999   2.9000001   3.5999999
  1.29999995  6.69999981  3.0999999   4.4000001   1.39999998  5.5999999   3.
  4.5         1.5         5.80000019  2.70000005  4.0999999   1.
  6.19999981  2.20000005  4.5         1.5         5.5999999   2.5
  3.9000001   1.10000002  5.9000001   3.20000005  4.80000019  1.79999995
  6.0999999   2.79999995  4.          1.29999995  6.30000019  2.5
  4.9000001   1.5         6.0999999   2.79999995  4.69999981  1.20000005
  6.4000001   2.9000001   4.30000019  1.29999995  6.5999999   3.          4.4000001
  1.39999998  6.80000019  2.79999995  4.80000019  1.39999998  6.69999981
  3.          5.          1.70000005  6.          2.9000001   4.5         1.5
  5.69999981  2.5999999   3.5         1.          5.5         2.4000001
  3.79999995  1.10000002  5.5         2.4000001   3.70000005  1.
  5.80000019  2.70000005  3.9000001   1.20000005  6.          2.70000005
  5.0999999   1.60000002  5.4000001   3.          4.5         1.5         6.
  3.4000001   4.5         1.60000002  6.69999981  3.0999999   4.69999981
  1.5         6.30000019  2.29999995  4.4000001   1.29999995  5.5999999   3.
  4.0999999   1.29999995  5.5         2.5         4.          1.29999995
  5.5         2.5999999   4.4000001   1.20000005  6.0999999   3.          4.5999999
  1.39999998  5.80000019  2.5999999   4.          1.20000005  5.
  2.29999995  3.29999995  1.          5.5999999   2.70000005  4.19999981
  1.29999995  5.69999981  3.          4.19999981  1.20000005  5.69999981
  2.9000001   4.19999981  1.29999995  6.19999981  2.9000001   4.30000019
  1.29999995  5.0999999   2.5         3.          1.10000002  5.69999981
  2.79999995  4.0999999   1.29999995  6.30000019  3.29999995  6.          2.5
  5.80000019  2.70000005  5.0999999   1.89999998  7.0999999   3.          5.9000001
  2.0999999   6.30000019  2.9000001   5.5999999   1.79999995  6.5         3.
  5.80000019  2.20000005  7.5999999   3.          6.5999999   2.0999999
  4.9000001   2.5         4.5         1.70000005  7.30000019  2.9000001
  6.30000019  1.79999995  6.69999981  2.5         5.80000019  1.79999995
  7.19999981  3.5999999   6.0999999   2.5         6.5         3.20000005
  5.0999999   2.          6.4000001   2.70000005  5.30000019  1.89999998
  6.80000019  3.          5.5         2.0999999   5.69999981  2.5         5.
  2.          5.80000019  2.79999995  5.0999999   2.4000001   6.4000001
  3.20000005  5.30000019  2.29999995  6.5         3.          5.5
  1.79999995  7.69999981  3.79999995  6.69999981  2.20000005  7.69999981
  2.5999999   6.9000001   2.29999995  6.          2.20000005  5.          1.5
  6.9000001   3.20000005  5.69999981  2.29999995  5.5999999   2.79999995
  4.9000001   2.          7.69999981  2.79999995  6.69999981  2.
  6.30000019  2.70000005  4.9000001   1.79999995  6.69999981  3.29999995
  5.69999981  2.0999999   7.19999981  3.20000005  6.          1.79999995
  6.19999981  2.79999995  4.80000019  1.79999995  6.0999999   3.          4.9000001
  1.79999995  6.4000001   2.79999995  5.5999999   2.0999999   7.19999981
  3.          5.80000019  1.60000002  7.4000001   2.79999995  6.0999999
  1.89999998  7.9000001   3.79999995  6.4000001   2.          6.4000001
  2.79999995  5.5999999   2.20000005  6.30000019  2.79999995  5.0999999
  1.5         6.0999999   2.5999999   5.5999999   1.39999998  7.69999981
  3.          6.0999999   2.29999995  6.30000019  3.4000001   5.5999999
  2.4000001   6.4000001   3.0999999   5.5         1.79999995  6.          3.
  4.80000019  1.79999995  6.9000001   3.0999999   5.4000001   2.0999999
  6.69999981  3.0999999   5.5999999   2.4000001   6.9000001   3.0999999
  5.0999999   2.29999995  5.80000019  2.70000005  5.0999999   1.89999998
  6.80000019  3.20000005  5.9000001   2.29999995  6.69999981  3.29999995
  5.69999981  2.5         6.69999981  3.          5.19999981  2.29999995
  6.30000019  2.5         5.          1.89999998  6.5         3.
  5.19999981  2.          6.19999981  3.4000001   5.4000001   2.29999995
  5.9000001   3.          5.0999999   1.79999995].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
>>>
```

And can you also explain why this reshape of array error is occurring?

**Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
train_data=np.delete(iris.data,test_index)
```

to:

```
train_data=np.delete(iris.data,test_index, axis=0)
```

And you will be good to go. As per the documentation of [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

> axis : int, optional
>
> ```
> The axis along which to delete the subarray defined by obj. 
>
> If axis is None, obj is applied to the flattened array.
> ```

Since you are not supplying that you want to delete the indices from row or column, numpy is flattening the array which would be wrong.

By using axis=0, we specify that we want to delete rows.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is this

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead
```

The following seems to be a suggestion generated by the library. Try as it tells you to. `reshape` is actually quite a useful technique to regularize input size for machine learning. It would further be a good practice to keep track of what shape you are inputting for training and testing.

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: I'm not able to figure out the new array size, can you please tell me.

Comment: May I ask where you took this code from? Whose idea was to use np.delete by index [0,50,100]? Do you know about the sample size and the number of features you want to train for.. also can be referred [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html)?